# Second Time Clicking First DataTable row hides second datatable's table head

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have two DataTables. On click of first DataTable td, I have load my second DataTable. 
When click on td of first DataTable second time, the header of second DataTable doesn't load.

**DataTable 1**

```
<table id="" class="display table table-striped table-bordered dt- 
responsive nowrap" style="width:100%" >
    <thead>           
        <tr>
        <th data-ng-repeat="(key, data) in dynamicContent.content[0]"> 
        {{key}}</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
       <tr data-ng-repeat="dataT in dynamicContent.content">
   <td data-ng-repeat="(key, data) in dataT" data-ng- 
        click="getfxdetailsbybranch(dataT)">{{data}}</td>
</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**DataTable 2**

```
 <table id="" class="display1 table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" style="width:100%" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-ng-repeat="(key, data) in dashboardfxdetails.content[0]">{{key}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr data-ng-repeat="dataT in dashboardfxdetails.content">
           <td data-ng-repeat="(key, data) in dataT">{{data}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('').DataTable();
 });
</script>
```

**Controller Layer**

1. Calling service layer that hits API and returns data.
2. Code :-

   ```
   fxUnassignedService
           .getunassignedFx($scope.fxdetails)
                   .then(
                           function(response) {
                               $scope.dynamicDataWithDetails = [];


   if($scope.dashboardfxdetails.headers.length>0)
                                   {

   $("table.display1").DataTable().destroy(true);
                                   }
   $scope.dashboardfxdetails = response.data.data;

   setTimeout(function() {$('table.display1').DataTable();}, 300);});
   ```

**RESULT**

Second Time click hides table header of second DataTable

Comment: There is a lot of code missing and this makes it impossible to help you. Try to make some full code snippet reproducing the problem you are facing and them probably someone is going to help you

Comment: Well i gave the needed information .. My html logic and service layer from controller from which the data is coming. kindly let me know if still anybody needs more info.